# Does Mail on OS X mark mail as read on the server or just locally?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Back when I used the Mail app on Leopard and Snow Leopard, it never seemed to tell the Gmail server that to mark as read the messages that I read. This had the annoying effect of requiring me to go to my web browser and mark everything as read there.

Needless to say, I didn't use it much since I would have to go to my web browser to mark it as read anyway.

Does the Mail app in El Captain have this problem? (I switched back to Windows a while back)

EDIT: I want to clarify that I want Mail to *automatically* mark messages as read as I read them, without having to do anything else. You know, how it normally works with every other email app.

Answer (score 1):

**Mail in OS X El Capitan doesn't have this problem.**

`Mark as Read` & `Mark as Unread` affect all of the devices linked to your IMAP account.

Comment: Note that Gmail is not exactly IMAP so this might not answer the question

Comment: I want to clarify that I meant if it automatically marks mail as read as you read them without any additional steps.